# What are some possible applications of a Data Scientist in an Engineering team (not to be confused with Data Engineering)?

Tags: careers

I have been trying to understand this for a long time, but this information proves to be incredibly elusive online.

What are possible jobs that a pure Data Scientist, without much background knowledge, could be hired for in an Engineering team? I am aware, for instance, that supply chain can get some involvement.

I don't mean the Business Intelligence positions, I want to get more involved with the engineering team, working on the products themselves (specially Aerospace or Railway). By "engineering" I mean working in the design phase of the product itself, rather than with post-market features (such as maintenance prediction).

Can a Data Scientist be useful in engineering, even without much domain knowledge?

Is there anyone familiar with this world that could provide some insight? Thank you

Comment: Usually data scientist seeks for patterns in some (big) data set. He should have certain 
 mathematical knowledge and would know certain algorithms. Typically, data scientist are employed for business intelligence, so you could work designing a traffic system (for railway or  airplanes) . In design of single type of product (i.e. aircraft) they typically do not employ data scientist except for statistical analysis of properties of certain material (materials science)

Comment: You posted this in several places, it requires opinions as there is no definitive answer, or intelligence…

Comment: the reason you can't find anything is because they're not really complementary fields that would normally work together.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am aware of the more general uses of Data Science. I'd like to know about the uses of Data Scientists in an Engineering setting. For instance, if you put "SpaceX data scientist LinkedIn" on Google, a few people come up, but I still can't find what exactly it is that they do.

Comment: @temporario1001 Message those folks on LinkedIn and flat out ask.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong forum; just go out and ask people. Cold-call them if you have to. Nonetheless...

A data scientist can contribute to anything touching engineering data. It's that wide open. You can perform characterization analyses, design calibrations, devise performance dashboards, fault prediction, module-matching, and on and on. Just think about an airplane manufacturer, smart-automobile manufacturer, etc. They have tons of data for their next and next-to-next product lines that are still in development, ready for a data savvy person to exploit. That engine in development has probably 100000 miles on it before it ships out.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's the wrong forum, but I just happen to be in this field.  I'm a Data Engineer, and I work with Data Scientists all the time.

A Data Scientist is just a Scientist who works with data instead of with physical things.  They are useful when exploring if your assumptions are correct.

For example, you might think a web shopping cart would perform better if you reordered or redesigned the checkout procedure.  Your typical developer would take the average checkout time before and after, and would declare victory.  A good data scientist would expand the mean measurement to include deviation analysis, realize that a normal distribution is the wrong fit, likely substituting a Poisson distribution, which alters how one compares the two means and deviations, resulting in a quantifiable outcome that sounds like "we are 67% certain that the old format was faster than the new one".

Many people get basic decision making wrong, because they have only been introduced to statistics or only remember statistics against the simplest (normal distribution) models.  I've seen people choose a faster mean when the standard deviations between the two measurements means the two distributions aren't significantly different.  I've seen people trust their mean as absolute when the standard deviation is so wide that many measurements would be negative in an impossible dimension, like time elapsed to complete a task.

Finally, the data scientist might also discover an analysis that leads to a new product, or a competitive edge in an existing one.

It is still Science though, often results will be inconclusive and the lack of results seem to be interpreted as failures.  The old Science joke remains: a business man sees 1000 failures, a scientist sees 1000 steps toward the discovery.

Comment: What would be the correct forum? Thanks for taking the time to write this reply :)